# How to display dropdownlist datavaluefield with 2 different attributes combined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table in **SQL**:

`WarehouseAddress(addressID, address1, address2, etc.)`

How can i display the datavaluefield in my dropdownlist as a combination of `address1` + `address2` separated by a comma?

This is my current **aspx.cs** code:

```
//reading the data from SQL
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataSource = warehouseAddressDB.getShippingAddresses(uid, wid);

//setting the data to be displayed in the dropdownlist
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataTextField = "address1";

//setting the value inside the dropdownlist when selected
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataValueField = "addressID";
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataBind();
```

I have tried using:

```
deliveryAddressDdl.DataTextField = "address1" + ", " + "address2";
```

But it just simply searches for the value `"address1, address2"` in sql, which simply does not exist in my `WarehouseAddress` table.

Thank you very much in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: what exactly u are trying?

Comment: 1. You can directly add that combination of column in your datasource and assign that column name directly to the database.

Comment: 2. You can loop through the datasource manually and add items to the dropdown. That way you can concat the value of both columns as a value to the dropdown item.

Comment: @Webruster basically, combining 2 attributes from database source, and displaying it into the dropdownlist. Imagine like a table's value in SQL `Country('country001', 'UK', 'europe')` and being displayed in the dropdownlist as `"UK, europe"`

Comment: Concate address1, and address2 in your sql select query with an Alias and then assign it to DataTextField. If you need the IDs too, you can concate that in sql query and assign it to DataValue Field.

Comment: What's inside `getShippingAddresses`?

Comment: @EmilioVicari compiling the `WarehouseAddress`es into a list with all of its attributes

Comment: Dinesh and Abdul's comments are on point. Which one is the best depends on how that function is implemented. If you can't get it working following their advice I suggest you post the relevant part of your `getShippingAddresses` function (i.e. where you load data from the database).

Comment: @EmilioVicari Yeah actually Abdul's comment helped me solve the problem, thus why I upvoted his comment. Should I delete the question now?

Comment: The best way to go about it would be [answering you own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @EmilioVicari will do, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question I asked earlier would be:

**aspx.cs:**

```
//reading the data from SQL
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataSource = warehouseAddressDB.getShippingAddresses(uid, wid);

//setting the data to be displayed in the dropdownlist
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataTextField = "combinedAddress";

//setting the value inside the dropdownlist when selected
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataValueField = "addressID";
    deliveryAddressDdl.DataBind();
```

**SQL:**

```
select *, (address1 + ',' + SPACE(1) + address2) as combinedAddress from WarehouseAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

you can combine that from your SQL statement and give it a column name address. see below example of code rewritten from your code.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT addressID, address1 + ' , ' + address2 AS Address FROM WarehouseAddress
```

Change in Source code for DataTextField:

```
 //reading the data from SQL
 deliveryAddressDdl.DataSource = warehouseAddressDB.getShippingAddresses(uid, wid);

//setting the data to be displayed in the dropdownlist
deliveryAddressDdl.DataTextField = "Address";

//setting the value inside the dropdownlist when selected
deliveryAddressDdl.DataValueField = "addressID";
deliveryAddressDdl.DataBind();
```

Comment: your answer has the right direction, but that select statement won't really work due to the lack of bracket

Comment: you mean , SELECT addressID, (address1 + ' , ' + address2) AS Address FROM WarehouseAddress ?   if it is Microsoft SQL Server it will work.